# Is the vonage box better between a cable modem and router?

Tags: router, home-networking

I'm having trouble where it makes the most sense to place the vonage phone box. Should I place it between my router and cable modem; or, should it be connected to the router? That is, does performance suffer or improve depending on either situation or am I over thinking this?

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  Any performance differences if they exist you won't be able to detect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It absolutely does not matter. I have had mine behind both a 100Mb router and currently a gigabit router and it works the a same.  The only real hassles are adding all the port forward entries to your router and possibly assigning a static ip to the voyage box.

```
4   Vonage1 5060    5061    10.10.0.100
5   Vonage4 10000   20000   10.10.0.100
6   Vonage2 53  53  10.10.0.100
7   Vonage3 69  69  10.10.0.100
```

(Use your own ip of course)
These entries allow my phones message light to turn on if I have pending voicemail. Check the voyage help pages for more info.  The entries are not plug and play.

Comment: I have my box connected to my router and didn't have to set anything up.